How to extract some information from IMDb web site using Python?
I was tring to scrape some information about tv shows for a university research.
I scraped from IMBd the url from all the top 250 tvshows from the web site https://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/. I stored them in a df named "tvshows_url" were in the first column we have the links and in the second one the titles.
Now I wanted to scrape from each url the User Reviews, the Stars, the Rating, the Popularity, the Genres and the Year and store them in a csv file.
I tried with the following code, but I can't extract the information I need. What am I doing wrong?
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def extract_info(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url,headers={'user-agent':'some-agent'}).content,"html.parser")
    
    # Extract user reviews
    user_reviews = soup.find('span', {'class': 'rating'}).text.strip()

    # Extract stars
    stars = soup.find('a', class_="ipc-metadata-list-item__icon-link").text.strip()

    # Extract rating
    rating = soup.find('span', class_="sc-bde20123-1 cMEQkK").get('content')

    # Extract popularity
    popularity = soup.find('div', class_="sc-5f7fb5b4-1 fTREEx").text.strip()
    
    # Extract genres
    genres = soup.find('a', class_="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link").get('content')
   
    # Extract year
    year = soup.find('a', lass="ipc-link ipc-link--baseAlt ipc-link--inherit-color").text.strip()
    
    return user_reviews, stars, rating, popularity, genres, year

# Apply the function to all url
extracted_info = tvshows_url['link'].apply(lambda x: extract_info(x))

# Create a DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(extracted_info.tolist(), columns=['User_Reviews', 'Stars', 'Rating', 'Popularity', 'Genres', 'Year'])
print(df)

#Export
df.to_csv('IMDV Top Tv Shows.csv')


https://developer.imdb.com/documentation/api-documentation/getting-access/…?

What you are doing wrong is that you are not using a more powerful framework. You should be using Selenium, which basically simulates the entire browser using Python, so you can mimic anything a regular user does and can do.
Here's how to get started:https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/
You can use any browser, there are so called runners for this, which are packages that open the browser and simulate anything.
You can target any element using either XSL or CSS.
I see you are using beautifulsoup, which is a more basic version of similar software.

Looking at the URL, The first movie is in "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/"
Examining the soup,
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/"
# Extract popularity
popularity = soup.find("div", class_="sc-5f7fb5b4-1 fTREEx", attrs={"data-testid": "hero-rating-bar__popularity__score"}).text.strip()

# The rest of the data you need can be found in this dictionary
all_data = json.loads(soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"}).text)


